# Generics types enumeration and static import cause ambiguous method issue

Tags: java, android

I must use various generic type `Palace`, `People`, `Apartment` for each I have created an enumeration class with a comparator to do comparation on multiple fields,

a sample of my enum class is this

```
enum PeopleComparator implements Comparator<People> {
    ID_SORT {
        public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.getId()).compareTo(o2.getId());
        }},
    NAME_SORT {
        public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
            return o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
        }};

    public static Comparator<People> decending(final Comparator<People> other) {
        return new Comparator<People>() {
            public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
                return -1 * other.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Comparator<People> getComparator(final PeopleComparator... multipleOptions) {
        return new Comparator<People>() {
           ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

in a main class to use the enum comparator, I must do 
    import static PeopleComparator.*;

to use the static comparator inside the enum in my class

now the problem is this:
In the same class I cannot do other static import

```
import static PalaceComparator.*;
```

and

```
import static ApartmentComparator.*;
```

because results ambiguous the static method `getComparator` since is present in all three enum.

How could I fix this issue without split my class?

Comment: Just write the full name, like ApartmentComparator.getComparator()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `import static` in this case. Just import the enum class and use `PalaceComparator.getComparator()`.

Comment: @GhostDerfel Sure but i have to wait the time countdown before click accept ;)

Comment: @AndreaF sorry for that :P get a little anxyous